# Access Form Field Logic

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, macros, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to make access conditionally only show rows that meet a certain condition, allow me to give you some background info before I proceed :

I've created an Access form and linked it to a test DB on my machine. The particular table I am interested in contains the following (important) rows :

ID , Office, Name, SecurityNumber

The thing is, ID is not unique. There are two Office locations, and each Office has it's own set of unique ID numbers. This means that ID 10 here and there may or may not be the same person. (this data comes out of a legacy security system we're not looking to change yet, so I cannot change it)

But ID -is- unique to each Office.

SO! I created an Access form with TABS! Two tabs, one for each office. What I am trying to achieve now is :

Have the ID/Name/SecurityNumber fields for each tab populate with only rows that match it's particular 'Office' value.

Thank you for reading and thank you for helping! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data for the office locations presented in separate tab page controls, you could use subforms on the pages which differ only in the WHERE clause of the queries used as their record sources.  So for the Office1 subform, the query could be:

```
SELECT ID, Office, [Name], SecurityNumber
FROM YourTable
WHERE Office = 'Office1'
ORDER BY [Name];
```

Then for Office2, the query would be the same except for the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Office = 'Office2'
```

As I understand your question, that approach would do what you're asking for.

However, that's not really the easy "Access way" to do it.  Instead consider a combo box control to allow your users to choose which office they want to view.  In the code for the combo's after update event, either modify the SELECT statement used as the form's record source or create a filter expression an apply it.

Also, since you're pulling the form's data from SQL Server, consider whether you want your form to load every record for the selected office location.  It may not be much concern if you have only a few to moderate number of rows for each location, but if you'll be dealing with multiple thousands of rows it could be.  In general, you should try to avoid pulling copious amounts of data across the wire; pull sparingly instead ... only what you need for the immediate task at hand.

Comment: Hi Hans! I was trying to achieve this with Macros. I gather from what you said that I should be looking to construct SQL queries and use that as a data source?

Comment: I see what you mean now, but for some reason my Office2 form fields all turned into #Deleted :( what is going on

Comment: I am using '=[dbo_Employee]![FirstName]' to select control source for one of the fields

Comment: @Kitler Let me try to catch up with your comments now.  First off, I would use VBA to modify a SELECT statement as the form's record source, or use VBA to create a filter on the record source.  I don't know if those tasks can be reasonably done with macros; I don't use macros.

Comment: I'm lost regarding the second comment.  Does that mean that the field values are displayed properly for Office1?  And it's only a problem for Office2?  If so what is different in the ways you implemented them?

Comment: With a form which includes a field named FirstName in its record source, I would expect a data control bound to that field to have only `FirstName` as its Control Source property.  What is `dbo_Employee`?  I'm guessing it's a link to a SQL Server table.  But, if so, isn't it included in your form's record source?  If it is, you shouldn't need to qualify the field name with its table name.  If it isn't part of the form's record source .... um ... what heck are you doing?  (Sorry, don't mean that to be offensive.  I'm just baffled.)

Comment: Seeing as how form property can only have one record source, and a tab cannot have it's own record source, I tried referring to different queries for different tabs, that's why I was using fully qualified names - 

Can I not do it this way? :( I get #Name? whenever I do =[Query1]![ID] or something similar.

Comment: You could place a subform on the tab; the subform can have its own record source separate from that of the main form.